# Error when installing bazel on windows

Tags: bazel

I am trying to install Bazel (version 0.10.0) on windows 7, but i have a problem when i try to excute compile.sh.

```
c.kazdghli@cKAZDGHL-STG-PC MINGW64 /c/Users/c.kazdghli/Downloads/bazel-0.10.0
$ export BAZEL_SH=c:/tools/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe

c.kazdghli@cKAZDGHL-STG-PC MINGW64 /c/Users/c.kazdghli/Downloads/bazel-0.10.0
$ export BAZEL_VS=c:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Microsoft\ visual\ studio

c.kazdghli@cKAZDGHL-STG-PC MINGW64 /c/Users/c.kazdghli/Downloads/bazel-0.10.0
$ export BAZEL_PYTHON=c:/Users/c.kazdaghli/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe

c.kazdghli@cKAZDGHL-STG-PC MINGW64 /c/Users/c.kazdghli/Downloads/bazel-0.10.0
$ ./compile.sh
ERROR: cannot locate python.exe; check your PATH.
       You may need to run the following command, or something
       similar, depending on where you installed Python:
         export PATH="/c/Python27:$PATH"

c.kazdghli@cKAZDGHL-STG-PC MINGW64 /c/Users/c.kazdghli/Downloads/bazel-0.10.0
$ export PATH=/c/Users/c.kazdaghli/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36:$PATH

c.kazdghli@cKAZDGHL-STG-PC MINGW64 /c/Users/c.kazdghli/Downloads/bazel-0.10.0
$ ./compile.sh
ERROR: cannot locate python.exe; check your PATH.
       You may need to run the following command, or something
       similar, depending on where you installed Python:
         export PATH="/c/Python27:$PATH"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem can be easily solved by the installing bazel from Chocolatey

Install Chocolatey with cmd.exe:

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

Then use the following command in cmd to install bazel:

```
choco install bazel --pre
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `which python.exe` after you `export` the new `PATH` and make sure the result is `/c/Users/c.kazdaghli/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe`.

Keep in mind that `which` operates by looking up the file in directories on the `PATH`, i.e. the `PATH` must contain the path to the directory where python.exe is, not the path of python.exe itself.

Comment: `$ which python.exe
which: no python.exe in (/c/Users/c.kazdaghli/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/)`

Comment: There it is: `/c/Users/.../Python36/python.exe` -- you have python.exe there, when in fact this should only be a directory. Maybe you ran `export PATH=/c/Users/.../Python36/python.exe:$PATH` instead of `export PATH="/c/Users/.../Python36:$PATH"`?

Comment: `c.kazdghli@cKAZDGHL-STG-PC MINGW64 ~
$ export PATH="/c/Users/c.kazdaghli/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36:$PATH"

c.kazdghli@cKAZDGHL-STG-PC MINGW64 ~
$ which python.exe
which: no python.exe in (/c/Users/c.kazdaghli/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36:/c/Users/c.kazdaghli/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36:/c/Users/c.kazdaghli/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/)
`